# Declaring multidimensional vector with variable number of dimensions in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I am trying to declare a multidimensional vector with variable number of dimensions (user input).

here is what I have:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector< double > data;

int main() {
    int numberDimensions = 4;
    for (int it = 0; it < numberDimensions; it++){
      // Nor sure what to put here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another solution is by using an if statement at the begining but I was wondering if another solution exists ?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numberDimensions = 4; 
    if (numberDimensions==0)
        cout << 'error' << endl;
    else if (numberDimensions==1)
         vector< double> data;
    else if (numberDimensions==2)
         vector< vector< double> > data;
    else if (numberDimensions==3)
         vector< vector< vector< double> > > data;
    else if (numberDimensions==4)
         vector< vector< vector< vector< double> > > > data;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Nested vectors won't give you terribly good performance. Consider using a flat vector of doubles with varying index calculation.

Comment: Your solution is not very useful. You won't be able to use `data` outside of those branches. You would need to reproduce your entire application logic for each branch (templates recommended). Consider defining a single vector with a size equal to the product of all of the dimensions` size.

Comment: This seems to be a very unwieldy solution to a separate problem. Perhaps if you told us more about what you are trying to accomplish we can help with a better solution?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, here is a more complete description of my probelm: my program take in input a configuration file in which the user defines a set of parameters (name, start value, end value and number of values for the parameter). I take those parameters and iterate over all the values the user wants. For each set of parameters I have a vector of results I want to save to a file. To avoid having one file per parameter set I'm trying to put all the results in a multidimensional vector and then save that vector.

Comment: Could you add an example of how your config file looks and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I would typically flatten that into a map with parameter names separated by something like periods (or any list of words) and a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments here is the solution I followed:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector< double > data;

int main() {

    std::vector<int> parameter1 {34,23,58};
    std::vector<int> parameter2 {1,2,3};

    data = vector< double > (parameter1.size()*parameter2.size());
    calculateResult(data);

   // If I want to access the result for Parameter1 = 58 and Parameter = 2 I do:
    int index1 = 2
    int index2 = 1
    double selectedResult = data[index1*parameter1.size()+index2];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would help to see `calculateResult(...)` to understand the result vector `data`. Also think of [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) to show a wider community that the problem is solved.

Comment: Unfortunately it is part of a more complex bit of code which would be too long to show. This solution works for me (I might look into maps also), I'll accept as soon as I can.